# How do i create a zero byte file in biztalk?

Tags: file-io, biztalk

I have a BizTalk system where I have a need to create Zero Byte file output.  Basically, I need to send out a report every day to our various partners.  If there is no data to send for the day, I still need to send a file, but there should be nothing in the file.

It seem that if there is no data to send, BizTalk just drops the whole thing and decides to send nothing.  I have read on how to read zero byte files in, but nothing on how to create them for sending out.

Does anyone have any recommendations or links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the link below. Some times you can have the answer.

http://biztalkwithshashikant.blogspot.com/2011/04/processing-empty-files-in-biztalk.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have seen this handled:

1. Modify the sample File Adapter in the BizTalk SDK to allow 0 byte files.
2. Create a custom Pipeline Component that detects a 0 length message and writes the 0 byte file using the same filename pattern as the Adapter.